# The new book about the Lubavitcher Rebbe zt"l

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, chabad, current-events

What is the response of the Lubavitcher rabbinate (as in Lubavitcher rabbis in general, I am not referring to any specific rabbinical body) to the [new book on the Rebbe zt"l by Josef Telushkin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0062318985)? Is it perceived to accurately portray the history of the Rebbe's life? Are there any book reviews available online written by prominent Lubavitcher Chasidim?

Comment: My local Chabad shliach has been enthusiastically promoting the book, so I guess at least as far as that goes, it's kosher mehadrin.

Comment: Mine, too, @Tatpurusha.

Comment: on the other hand, see http://www.collive.com/show_news.rtx?id=30851 and http://www.chabadinfo.com/?url=article_en&id=33483

Comment: Although the second is more at Rabbi Miller.

Comment: Same here @Tatpurusha. In fact, he has been praising all 2 or 3 of the recent biographical works on the Rebbe.

Comment: After rereading the book and speaking to others about it the Telushkin book is great for those who don't know anything or very little about the Rebbe. It presents a very practical book on the Rebbe's leadership in a very practical and real way. That being said the advantage is mainly for those visiting a chabad house and not those already being raised is lubavitch house and receiving a lubavitch education

Answer (score 4, accepted):

chabad.org Lubavitch's primary online voice carries a fine review of the book: http://www.chabad.org/news/article_cdo/aid/2619597/jewish/Biography-of-the-Rebbe-Hits-New-York-Times-Best-Seller-List.htm

It would seem they strongly approve.